# "Fail though I did"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, writing-style, semantics, subordinate-clauses

I have found the following sentence :

> Fail though I did, I would not abandon my goal.

The adverbial clause "*Fail though I did*" (instead of, "*Even though I failed*") seems quite stylistic. But what's the grammatical rules for such usage?

Comment: Yes; it's a very formal, archaic usage. Obviously, 'Though I failed' and 'Though I _did_ fail' are near-exact modern equivalents (and your insertion of 'even' highly idiomatic). There are few related common usages; 'Try as I might' is a fossilised look-alike, but I'd say quite different in substructure.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, can we say "Though did he invite me ..." in place of "Though he invited me ...", following this structure?

Comment: Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: "Though did he invite me" implies that the invitation was not been extended.